# xrandr --listproviders not showing any graphics cards

Tags: nvidia, xorg, xrandr, wayland, x11-forwarding

I would like to be able to have `xrandr` recognize my two RTX 3070 Nvidia Graphics Cards.

However, xrandr does not return anything.

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 0
```

I am using `nvidia-prime` and `nvidia-driver-530`.

I believe that this is caused by `Xwayland` running an X composition layer on top of `wayland` and not running `xorg` directly.

Although I don't really know if `wayland` is actually the root cause, I believe I would like to disable all `wayland` on my server machine (Ubuntu Server 22.04) and run `xorg` only. I am accessing the server through `ssh -X` from a Ubuntu desktop client.

```
xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*XWAYLAND15 3840/620x2160/330+0+0  XWAYLAND15
```

```
xinput
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
tty
```

```
loginctl show-session 1 -p Type
Type=tty
```

What settings or configuration would I need to get `xrandr --listproviders` to display the Nvidia graphics cards?

I would be happy to provide additional details as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, what I was trying to do did not seem possible.

Since I do not think the graphics software is meant to be run this way on a headless Ubuntu server, I installed `lightdm` so I could access a GUI on the server machine and connect it directly to the monitor with a direct video connection.

With the GUI installed, everything seemed to work fine with all the Nvidia cards being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You should use applications like `lshw` and `nvidia-smi` when using `ssh -X` as they will be actually ran on your remote system showing you the hardware in that system.  `ssh -X` will only show you your local monitors and video card(s) when `xrandr` is ran on the remote system.  The reason is that you are forwarding the display calls to your local host when those commands are run.  `lshw` and `nvidia-smi` will run on the remote system fine and show you what hardware you have.

To give examples I have two hosts here sitting side by side.  One has a GTX 1060 in it and the other a GTX 1650:

*Local system:*

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x1b7 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 3
 0: +*DVI-D-1 1920/521x1080/293+1920+0  DVI-D-1
 1: +DVI-D-0 1280/338x1024/270+3840+0  DVI-D-0
 2: +HDMI-0 1920/509x1080/286+0+0  HDMI-0
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for terrance: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:36 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:de000000-dfffffff ioport:ef00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: VESA VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1280,1024
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Apr 27 07:13:38 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.41.03              Driver Version: 530.41.03    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB     Off| 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   58C    P0               31W / 120W|    534MiB /  6144MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3031      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          348MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3306      G   xfwm4                                         2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3413      G   /usr/local/bin/ckb-next                       1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    137496      G   ...,WinRetrieveSuggestionsOnlyOnDemand       38MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    141190      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                    139MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

*Remote system (connected via `ssh -X`):*

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ssh -X intrepid
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-71-generic x86_64)

  System information as of Thu Apr 27 07:12:42 AM MDT 2023

  System load:  0.02                Processes:              222
  Usage of /:   73.4% of 454.44GB   Users logged in:        0
  Memory usage: 9%                  IPv4 address for bond0: 10.0.0.220
  Swap usage:   0%                  IPv4 address for tun0:  10.8.0.1

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

You have new mail.
Last login: Thu Apr 27 07:02:50 2023 from 10.0.0.100
-------------------------------------------------------------- 04/27/23 07:12:43
terrance@Intrepid:~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x1b7 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
-------------------------------------------------------------- 04/27/23 07:12:53
terrance@Intrepid:~$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 3
 0: +*DVI-D-1 1920/521x1080/293+1920+0  DVI-D-1
 1: +DVI-D-0 1280/338x1024/270+3840+0  DVI-D-0
 2: +HDMI-0 1920/509x1080/286+0+0  HDMI-0
-------------------------------------------------------------- 04/27/23 07:13:01
terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:de000000-dfffffff ioport:ef00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: VESA VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=640,480
-------------------------------------------------------------- 04/27/23 07:13:16
terrance@Intrepid:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Apr 27 07:13:25 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.105.17   Driver Version: 525.105.17   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 35%   41C    P8    11W /  75W |      1MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
-------------------------------------------------------------- 04/27/23 07:13:25
```

As you can see the `xrandr` command will show exactly the same when ran on both my local host and the remote host. But the `lshw` and `nvidia-smi` show exactly what I need to see on both hosts.

Comment: Thank you for the information. What I am trying to do is set variables for rendering Nvidia offline `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD_PROVIDER=NVIDIA-G0` and `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD_PROVIDER=NVIDIA-G1`. However, the server does not seem to be able to select or find those names. That is the true issue that I want to resolve because I am unable to select the graphics card I want to use at will. I am able to see the graphics cards with `lshw` and `nvidia-smi`, but still unable to find a way to select the offload provider.

Comment: Would I have to be running an Xsession to recognize the Nvidia cards as offload providers? I'm not running any GUI or remote desktop, and only using a virtual terminal to access the server. Is there a way to get the Nvidia cards recognizes as offload providers through the virtual or local terminal?